# Transform the content of string columns following a pattern in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a `.csv` file like the one below:

```
id                info1                                  info2             
1        abcd/145.7851548/1.png                  efgh/456.1425698/2.png
2        cbhy/558.4526988/3.png                  dhfy/786.8965245/4.png
```

I want to transform both columns in this way:

```
id             info1                            info2             
1        abcd/51548/1.png                  efgh/25698/2.png
2        cbhy/26988/3.png                  dhfy/65245/4.png
```

The goal is to keep only the last 5 digits of the path in the middle. For example, abcd/145.78**51548**/1.png (only highlighted part remains). 
Could anyone tell me how can I achieve it?
I tried to use **pd.str.split**, but it seems to not work.

Comment: Will it always be a single digit in the filename? e.g `1.png` not `12.png`? You can use the `.str` accessor with an index, like `df['column'].str[-11:]` but it's going to be dependent on your actual data

Comment: _I have a .csv file like the one below:_ That's not valid CSV. _I tried to use pd.str.split, but it seems to not work._ What does that mean, exactly? **Please provide a [mcve].**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
cols=["info1", "info2"]
df[cols]=df[cols].replace(r"(.*/).*(.{5}/.*)", r"\1\2", regex=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
   id             info1             info2
0   1  abcd/51548/1.png  efgh/25698/2.png
1   2  cbhy/26988/3.png  dhfy/65245/4.png
```

In essence the regex will match the piece until first slash, inclusive: `(.*/)` (due to square brackets - group 1).

Then for the middle part - it will match anything (or nothing), followed by exactly 5 characters, slash and again - anything and nothing: `.*(.{5}/.*)`. Having again as a group (2) everything as of exactly 5 characters inclusive.

Then the whole thing will get replaced by exactly group 1, followed by group 2: `\1\2`.

Comment: `df.replace(r"(.*/).*(.{5}/.*)", r"\1\2",regex=True)`

Comment: @DYZ ```regex=True``` is a default, at least in a version, which I'm using...

Comment: Ou, now I got you! Theoretically speaking- you're right, but practically, which one's faster for multiple columns, when not all you want to do this regex on?

Comment: Ok - switched to what you said, but with explicitly declared columns I want to do this change for;) makes more sense this way, thanks!

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinski thank you very much!! But still I am not fully understood your solution. What if my file path something like this? abcd/145.7851548/658.2486874/1.png   how regex changes? sorry I am fairly new to python language.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it worked. And you would like to change which ones from that new string? (Second split, or second and third?)

Comment: I would like to keep like this...  abcd/51548/86874/1.png. meaning 2nd and 3rd.. to split both. thanks @Grzegorz Skibinski

Comment: Gotcha, you can Try: ```df[cols]=df[cols].replace(r"(.*/).*(.{5}/).*(.{5}/.*)", r"\1\2\3", regex=True)```

Comment: you are awesome @Grzegorz Skibinski!! Thank you very much.